# adapt impressionist gem to mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mongoid

I'm trying adapt this gem, https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist to **mongoid** odm.

I have been seeing the commit for **mongo_mapper** in https://github.com/tute/impressionist/commit/1c3f809da8ebd3ced8cb9bda8caee89012091a10.

This is impression.rb model for mongoid:

```
class Impression
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  field :impressionable_type, :type => String
  field :impressionable_id, :type => String
  field :user_id, :type => String
  field :controller_name, :type => String
  field :action_name, :type => String
  field :view_name, :type => String
  field :request_hash, :type => String
  field :ip_address, :type => String
  field :session_hash, :type => String
  field :message, :type => String
  field :referrer, :type => String
end
```

After generate the file for mongoid fine:

```
rails g impressionist --orm mongo_id
      invoke  mongo_id
      create  config/initializers/impression.rb
```

I try run the server and I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant Impressionist::Engine::MongoId (NameError)
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails32/gems/impressionist-1.1.1/lib/impressionist/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>'
```

In `engine.rb` file I have:

```
require "impressionist"
require "rails"

module Impressionist
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    initializer 'impressionist.model' do |app|
      require "#{root}/app/models/impressionist/impressionable.rb"
      if Impressionist.orm == :mongo_id
        require "impressionist/models/mongo_id/impression.rb"
        require "impressionist/models/mongo_id/impressionist/impressionable.rb"
        MongoId::Document.plugin Impressionist::Impressionable
      end
    end

    initializer 'impressionist.controller' do
      ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
        include ImpressionistController::InstanceMethods
        extend ImpressionistController::ClassMethods
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The line 11 is `MongoId::Document.plugin Impressionist::Impressionable`

can anyone help out? Thank you

Comment: Will you change to Mongoid::Document.plugin Impressionist::Impressionable and see if it fixes your issue?

Comment: I have made every changes like commit https://github.com/tute/impressionist/commit/1c3f809da8ebd3ced8cb9bda8caee89012091a10. Also, I have updated the model in question. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: @hyperrjas... did you do what I suggested?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I have removed `Mongoid::Document.plugin` and now run the server fine :D. I go to check if the gem works fine :D. Thank you @JesseWolgamott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line 11

```
MongoId::Document.plugin Impressionist::Impressionable
```

Should be

```
Mongoid::Document.plugin Impressionist::Impressionable
```

Note the capitalization of `Mongoid`.